# How do I get a new mechanic after I killed the current one?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I killed my mechanic.
So he no longer answers his phone to bring me a car. I tried buying a new apartment and that didn't worlk.
It's been days since I killed him and noone picks up his phone.

How do I get a new mechanic? Or can I revive him in some way?

Comment: Why would you kill your mechanic?!

Comment: Can you reload to a previous save?

Comment: @Ryan Because he sometimes just randomly drives off with your car or because it was an accident while making a U-turn. It's GTA. Stuff happens.

Comment: @Strike Good point. I was thinking the person meant intentionally killing the mechanic.

Comment: Really?? I kill my mechanic twice a day... and he always respawns. :(

Comment: @Ryan So help me god, if he changes the radio to channel X one more time..

Answer (score 2):

I have found [here](http://gtaforums.com/topic/617020-killed-personal-mechanic/)  that you just might be in a bad location for him.   Try moving to a different area in the map and give him a call.

A few users have reported killing the mechanic multiple times... (every time he shows up)...

Comment: Yup! Can't get my mechanic to stay 6 feet under. I have to keep running him over with my car, but he never learns :-/

Comment: @Dom, please upvote the answer if you agree or find that answer correct! :)

Answer (score 1):

I kill my mechanic nearly every time!

The problem may be with the bill paying system. You have to pay your mechanic every day, or 40ish minutes real time.

The problem arises when you miss a bill payment: you have to then wait another day to pay him, but if you do anything other than sit in free mode for 40 mins, including Races or Missions, it resets and you have to begin again. You should try just driving around on your own or having some fun in free mode for a while with your friends.